# Visual studio 2013 C++ standard library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am using visual studio 2013 to program the following code in c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2; 
    int current = std::min(v1, v2);
    int max = std::max(v1, v2);
    while (current <= max)
    {
        std::cout << current << std::endl;
        ++current;
    }
    return 0;

}
```

This code was meant to solve: "Write a program that prompts the user for two integers.
Print each number in the range specified by those two integers."

I was confused at first, but found that std min/max could help after searching. However, I am getting errors when trying to compile, telling me that namespace "std" has no member "min" and no member "max."

Did I do something wrong, or does Visual Studio 2013 not include min/max?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min

Comment: Just add `#include <algorithm>` to your code.

Comment: With emphasis on the (unfortunately very small text) "Defined in header `<algorithm>`"

Comment: I found the answer by googling "c++ min and max". Why couldn't you?

Comment: lol - I googled c++ std min and max and this was the top hit. As so often happens, it's a closed question on SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks to me like you forgot to `#include <algorithm>`.

Your code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm> // notice this

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: " << std::endl;
    int v1 = 0, v2 = 0;
    std::cin >> v1 >> v2; 
    int current = std::min(v1, v2);
    int max = std::max(v1, v2);
    while (current <= max)
    {
        std::cout << current << std::endl;
        ++current;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Add

```
#include <algorithm>
```

before using [**`std::min`** or **`std::max`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)