# Installing OpenCV 2.4.10 on Windows 8.1 with VS 2013

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install opencv 2.4.10 on Windows 8.1. Normally I install OpenCV without any third party libraries but this time I am trying to install some libraries like CStripes, Eigen, OpenExr, CUDA 6.5, AMD Blas and Fft.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 64-bit. OpenCV installation without any third party library completes without any issues but with 3rd party libraries it is unsuccessful. I was following the installation procedure given [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html#windows-installation).

The issue that I noticed is that during the installation the system cannot find the `.lib` and `.dll` files e.g.

- `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\..\lib\Release\opencv_contrib2410.lib'`
- `file INSTALL cannot find "E:/opencv/build/bin/Release/opencv_gpu2410.dll".`

I ran the installation as an admin but I was still getting the same errors.

You can view the Visual Studio build log [here](http://notepad.cc/bicauju69) and Cmake build log [here](http://notepad.cc/qizbisy2).

Please help me out.

Comment: Search for "Error" in the Visual Studio logs. There is clearly a CUDA error being thrown: E:/opencv/sources/modules/gpu/src/nvidia/core/NCV.cu(356): error : namespace "std" has no member "max"

Comment: Look here for possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541762/visual-studio-2013-c-standard-library

Comment: @BeRecursive Thanks for the pointing that out. I had to change the source of NCV.cu and everything ran. So, should I add an answer to this question or would you like to add it?
Another thing that should this thing be raised as an issue in OpenCV community as this change was made in their source?

Comment: I added the answer, I suggest you do raise that as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "Error" in the Visual Studio logs. There is clearly a CUDA error being thrown:

```
E:/opencv/sources/modules/gpu/src/nvidia/core/NCV.cu(356): error : namespace "std" has no member "max"
```

It seems as though you need to add `#include <algorithm>` for this to work (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541762/visual-studio-2013-c-standard-library)).

I would also suggest that you raise this as a bug on the OpenCV tracker!

Comment: Yeah I had to include `#include <algorithm>` in NCV.cu. Thanks for the help. I'll raise the issue.